# Remove duplicates from list, including original matching item

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I tried searching and couldn't find this exact situation, so apologies if it exists already.

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a list as well as the original item I'm searching for. If I have this:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

I want to end up with this:

```
ls = [1, 2]
```

I know that using set will remove duplicates like this:

```
print set(ls)  # set([1, 2, 3])
```

But it still retains that `3` element which I want removed. I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the duplicates and original matching items too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `list.count`:

```
>>> ls = [1, 2, 3, 3]
>>> [x for x in ls if ls.count(x) == 1]
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Here is a [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures) on both of those.

---

**Edit:**

@Anonymous made a good point below.  The above solution is perfect for small lists but may become slow with larger ones.

For large lists, you can do this instead:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ls = [1, 2, 3, 3]
>>> c = Counter(ls)
>>> [x for x in ls if c[x] == 1]
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I need to use list comprehension more.

Comment: This is O(N^2), which is fine for small lists, but will be slow for larger ones. You can fix it by counting occurrences first: `c = collections.Counter(ls); uniqs = [x for x in ls if c[x] == 1]`

Answer (score 0):

If items are contigious, then you can use `groupby` which saves building an auxillary data structure in memory...:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice

data = [1, 2, 3, 3]
# could also use `sorted(data)` if need be...
new = [k for k, g in groupby(data) if len(list(islice(g, 2))) == 1]
# [1, 2]
```